# Magento 2 Set current store

Tags: magento2

I have the following Magento 1 code and i would like to know the Magento 2 equivalent of the code.

I've looked around on the web but unable to find a proper solution.

```
  Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
 */

 protected $_storeManager;

public function __construct(
\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
) {
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
}
```

// now you can set your current store like

```
$this->_storeManager->setCurrentStore('YOUR_STORE_ID');
```

Comment: Thanks. how can i retrieve **Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID**  in Magento 2 or do i just replace this code with a **0** which seems to be the equivalent for  **Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID** which is the id of the admin panel?

Comment: You can directly set It to 0 for admin store id, because admin store always is 0 and in Magento2  ADMIN_STORE_ID  constact is Obsolete @Jiyaad.D

Comment: It is not switching store, whenever i visit storefront, only default store is visible. Am i missing something?

Comment: Hi @vinit-chouhan, Did you make the change of store view? How have you solved this problem?