# Switch store programatically magento 2

Tags: magento2, multistore, store-switcher

I am trying to switch stores programatically. I used following code to achieve it :

```
/**
* @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
*/

protected $_storeManager;

public function __construct(
 \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
) {
$this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
}
```

and then :

```
$this->_storeManager->setCurrentStore('YOUR_STORE_ID');
```

as given in https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/173763/59686

But no success. Only default store is displayed(selected) on storefront.

I have also tried this url scheme `http://mystoreurl.com/?___store=storeId` but it only display the store with given id instead of switching the store completely, Means when i visit the main url (`http:mystoreurl.com`), it is again displaying default store.
Is there any way to switch the store programatically just like it is **selected as default** from admin.

Or is there any way to add some readymade widget to switch stores (Store Switcher). The theme i am using does not have this feature to auto populate store switcher as default Magento Luma theme provides.